# Dropdown Menu Items are going down

Tags: html, css

I have a dropdown menu that contains the List of products of our company.I have an product names `Hotel Management Solutions` which i am trying to show in single line of dropdown menu but is coming in multiple lines.

Here Is the Fiddle..

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h97gf/)

Here is the HTML code..

```
<nav>
<ul style="padding-left: 3px">
    <li><a href="#">Products</a>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Hotel Management Solutions </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
       </li>
      </ul>
</nav>
```

Please help me to display the content in One line only..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `white-space:nowrap` to `nav ul ul`:

```
nav ul ul {
    background: #5f6975;
    border-radius: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

**[See Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h97gf/3/)**

This will keep each list item on a single line without needing to set a fixed width.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/h97gf/6/  Why is my second option coming to middle instead of left side

Comment: Actually Sir i need all the items to start from same position from left side  ..What to add for this?

Comment: @user3664608 They are in the middle because you have `text-align:center`. They are pushed out to the right because you have `padding: 1px 40px;` Take a look at **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h97gf/8/)** and read the comments I put. It should fix all of your problems.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this style

```
ul > li > ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the only solution to this problem is to change the width of products div in the css

```
nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 25px 20px;
    color: #00a1e4;
    text-decoration: none;
    width:250px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your nav ul ul li a property declaration with this

```
nav ul ul li a {
    padding: 1px;
    color: #fff;
    width: 200px;

}
```